# AngularJS filter comparator true while displaying ng-repeat list when input field is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going off by this example fiddle where it demonstrates the use of comparator parameter to filter exact matches....:

http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

priority is a number from 1-100, but I have it input as text and filtered as string
so any data that includes a substring will also pass through the ng-repeat...like when I type 1 it will also display 11, 111, 132 etc...which is how I came across the :true comparator.

I've read other stackflow answers suggesting to write custom filter functions but with the true comparator it looks like I can achieve what I want just by:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search.priority"
  title='Priority number to filter by'
  ng-model="search.priority" >

<tr ng-repeat="workflowItem in workflows | filter:search:true">
  <td>{{workflowItem.priority}}</td>
```

where it does only filter the exact matches. However, obviously it does not pass anything when the input field is empty since nothing matches the empty string.

My question is: Is there a way I can allow ng-repeat to still display everything when the field is empty while keeping the exact match filter?  Appreciate everyone's time!

Comment: Check the jsfiddle url.

Comment: My understanding is that the filter filter will return all elements when the predicate is an empty string.  See http://jsfiddle.net/3aD8N/.

Comment: Sorry - I see the issue now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll want to use a custom comparator function.  It will allow you to perform a strict comparison except when the predicate is falsy.

Your markup would then be:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search.priority"
  title='Priority number to filter by'
  ng-model="search.priority" >

<tr ng-repeat="workflowItem in workflows | filter:search:exceptEmptyComparator">
 <td>{{workflowItem.priority}}</td>
```

And define the comparator function on your controller:

```
$scope.exceptEmptyComparator = function (actual, expected) {
    if (!expected) {
       return true;
    }
    return angular.equals(expected, actual);
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hey Joel- Thanks for the help!! I think I'm going down the right path, one thing though- could you explain to me how the parameter of (actual, expected) works? what is it pointing to? am I supposed to set them to the actual and expected values inside the function?

Comment: Angular will take care of that for you - you just provide a function on the scope that has the custom comparator signature.  For each element in the array Angular will call the comparator function and pass in "search" as expected and the element as "actual".  So we say, if the expected or "search" is empty, then match ALL elements (return true).  Otherwise, perform a 'strict' object comparison.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/hQ7CP/.

Comment: so is expected and actual like keywords? how does it know to pass "search" as expected and element as "actual"? I'm sorry im such a noob ;(

Comment: Those are just regular function parameters.  You're providing the comparator function to the 'filter' filter.  It will call your function for each element in the array, passing the element as the first parameter ('actual') and 'search' as the second parameter ('expected').  Set a breakpoint on the comparator and step through it to see it in action.  Hope that helps.

Comment: To quote angularJS's developer guide: "The injected argument (the exceptEmptyComparator function) is a function that takes the value to format as first argument(expected) and filter parameters starting with the second argument (actual)."  Is what I was looking for am I right? Thanks a lot Joel i really appreciate your help + explanation I marked your answer.

Comment: Wait ...that's from the http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter for creating custom filter functions....but does this apply to regular functions also hence the first argument is always going to be  value to compare / format and second argument is always going to be the value to compare /filter? i'm guessing it applies to regular functions also ??

Comment: I was specifically speaking to the 'filter' filter.  It's confusing.  There's the filter that's *called* 'filter', and it offers the means to specify a custom comparator function.  Then there's a totally different thing called custom filters, which is a whole other ball of wax.  That's where you roll your own.  In your case that would mean iterating through the array and calling the custom comparator.