# Angular function filter comparator example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Can someone give me an example of how to use Angular filter comparator?

From official doc:

> function(actual, expected): The function will be given the object value and the predicate value to compare and should return true if the item should be included in filtered result.

There is a great blog post talking about Angular filter:
[Fun with AngularJS filters - Part 1: the `filter` filter](http://sarahbranon.com/post/69604997957/fun-with-angularjs-filters-part-1-the-filter)

However, at the end of it, where I am looking for some useful example of the function comparator, I still found nothing.

> For more particular matching needs, you can pass a function instead of a boolean as the comparator argument.

I have tried few combinations by myself. Neither adding the function at the end of the expression or pointing to a function in scope do the work.

Comment: example of how to use- copy and paste in editor for formatting: var directory = [{phone: '(+1)408-777-1234'}, {phone: '(+1)813-331-8797'}, {phone: '(+1)606-331-8797'},{phone: '(+91)966-871-1089'},phone: '(+91)813-331-8797'}];
    var country = 'India';
    var criteria = {phone: '813-331-8797'};
    
    $filter('filter')(data, criteria, function(actPhone, expPhone) {
         return actPhone == '(' + (c == 'India')? 91 : 1 + ')' + expPhone;
    })

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21200007/404522 for an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did something like this, since Angular iterates on objects and tries to compare them whole as well as recursively their individual properties.

```js
// in your controller
$scope.filterMyData = function (input, search_param) {
  if (input && input.propertyWeCareAbout) {
    // it's ugly, but to quickly get something done you can ignore search_param 
    return input.propertyWeCareAbout === $scope.SomeOtherData;
  }
  else {
    return angular.equals(input, search_param);
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Quick search: </span><input type="search" ng-model='quickSearch'/><br/>


<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="obj in someHttpService.dataAsArray | filter:quickSearch:filterMyData">
    <td>{{ obj.key }} </td>
    <td>{{ obj.propertyWeCareAbout }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In my case, "quickSearch" is largely meaningless, and filtering was done by a different logic. You can always just chain another filter at the end by adding "| filter:quickSearch" into ng-repeat.

Answer (score 27):

**DETAILED EXPLANATION ON HOW `filter : expression : comparator` works.**

This is the filter syntax:

```
data | filter: expression : comparator
```

The AngularJS built-in `filter` function provides a non-case sensitive substring search on the data it is passed, comparing against the `expression` when the expression is a string or a property of an object subject to the filter. The `comparator` gives you the ability to further refine the filter. If you simply specify the `comparator` as `true`, it will ensure that only items which are an exact match to the `expression` are returned. A more flexible approach is to specify the `comparator` as a function which returns a [predicate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344021/2298108).

**EXAMPLES**

With the following data exposed in a view's `$scope` as people:

```
var people = [
    {name:'John Jones',location:'Peterborough'},
    {name:'Angela Atkinson',location:'Jersey'},
    {name:'Peter Peterjon',location:'Attleborough'}
];
```

We'll set up a simple input search box on the view, which we'll give as the filter expression parameter:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search People">
```

1) **WITHOUT COMPARATOR**

The results of the search will be output where we invoke the filter:

```
<p ng-repeat="person in people | filter : searchText">{{person.name}} {{person.location}}</p>
```

If we type 'J' into the search box, because all entries have a j somewhere, the result will still show all 3 entries.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/VID2CAKvUI5mjgKLImaI?p=preview

2) **WITH COMPARATOR AS `true`**

```
<p ng-repeat="person in people | filter : searchText : true">{{person.name}} {{person.location}}</p>
```

Typing 'J' will show no results as there is no field which is exactly J. We'll only get a result if any of the following are typed in (case sensitive):

- John Jones
- Peterborough
- Angela Atkinson
- Jersey
- Peter Peterjon
- Attleborough

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/hhw2u03egXsUo7IyGc1w?p=preview

3) **WITH COMPARATOR AS `function`**

We'll attach a custom comparator [predicate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344021/2298108) called `customComparator` to the `$scope` of the controller. I set it up to require a full match but it's no longer case sensitive. We use it as follows:

```
<p ng-repeat="person in people | filter : searchText : customComparator">{{person.name}} {{person.location}}</p>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Iy9r9bLQQdzefuzUv0TD?p=preview

4) **CUSTOM FILTER**

Instead of using the built in `filter` with expression and comparator we can just create a custom filter and pipe `|` into that. Such a custom filter which does exactly the same as **WITH COMPARATOR AS `function`** above might look like this:

```
.filter('customFilter',[function() {

    var customFilter = function(arr,searchText){

      if(! searchText)
        return arr;

      return arr.filter(function(arrayItem){

          var match = false;

          for(var key in arrayItem) {
              if(! arrayItem.hasOwnProperty(key) || key === '$$hashKey')
                 continue;

              if(arrayItem[key].toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()) {
                match = true;
                break;
              }
           }

           return match;

       });
    };

    return customFilter;

}])
```

and it would be used as follows:

```
<p ng-repeat="person in people | customFilter : searchText">{{person.name}} from {{person.location}}</p>
```

Note that this syntax is not `expression : comparator`. Instead, it is `customFilter : filterArgument`.

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/wWT3cjfy7867WUSqqSKj?p=preview