# How to show all values when AngularJS strict filter field is empty?

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which can be filtered by several columns. The filter is strict. When the data is initiated, it shows all values. However, after filtering by some column and getting back to empty option to show all values, it shows an empty table. How to apply a strict filter only to non-empty values?

```
<select
    ng-model="search.column1">
    <option value=''></option>
    <option ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample value="{{e.column1}}">{{e.column1}}</option>
</select> 

<select
    ng-model="search.column2">
    <option value=''></option>
    <option ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample value="{{e.column2}}">{{e.column2}}</option>
</select> 

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample | filter:search:true">
        <td>{{ e.column1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ e.column2 }}</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i think issue is remove true option ( | filter:search)

Comment: I know but if I would have 'some' and 'some data' values and choose to filter by 'some', it would show both. I need strict comparator for several fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created custom filter in controller:

```
$scope.filterMyData = function (input, searchParam) {

     if (searchParam == '')
          return true;

     return angular.equals(input, searchParam);
}
```

And changed to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample | filter:search:filterMyData">
```

Comment: Thanks @Justas. I ran into the same issue, and your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue was in the use of `filter`:

You should change `filter:search:true` to `filter:search`.

The third parameter the [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is a comparator. In this case, you don't need it:

> Comparator which is used in determining if values retrieved using
>   expression (when it is not a function) should be considered a match
>   based on the expected value (from the filter expression) and actual
>   value (from the object in the array).

If you want to learn more a bit about comparators, I recommand you to read [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519794/angular-function-filter-comparator-example) (SO).

---

Working snippet of your code:

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.getExample = [{
    'column1': 1,
    'column2': 2
  }, {
    'column1': 3,
    'column2': 4
  }, {
    'column1': 5,
    'column2': 6
  }];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController as vm">
  <select ng-model="search.column1">
    <option value=''></option>
    <option ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample" value="{{e.column1}}">{{e.column1}}</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="search.column2">
    <option value=''></option>
    <option ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample" value="{{e.column2}}">{{e.column2}}</option>
  </select>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="e in vm.getExample | filter:search">
      <td>{{ e.column1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ e.column2 }}</td>
      <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I need strict filter because if I would have 'some' and 'some data' values and choose to filter by 'some', it would show both.